# Set server address dynamically in ideablade for second time?

Tags: c#, wpf, database-connection, devforce

I have this problem that in my program I set dynamically server address and try to connect to my database and it works fine if the address that I provided was correct, if not it doesn't connect and that's normal. After that I would like to change this address, but even though I change it in code and try to connect with my database again, it stills remembers old configuration and still doesn't connect. What should I do to change it?

I set my configuration like this:

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.Load(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile);
        foreach (XmlElement element in xmlDoc.DocumentElement)
        {
            if (element.Name.Equals("ideablade.configuration"))
            {
                foreach (XmlNode ele in element.ChildNodes)
                {
                    if (ele.Name == "objectServer")
                    {
                        var node = ele;
                        node.Attributes["remoteBaseURL"].Value = remoteBaseURL;
                        node.Attributes["serverPort"].Value = serverPort;
                        node.Attributes["serviceName"].Value = serviceName;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        xmlDoc.Save(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile);
        ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("ideablade.configuration");
```

and I try to connect to my databse like this

```
if (BeczkaModel!= null)
        {
            BeczkaModel.Disconnect();
            BeczkaModel= null;
        }

IdeaBladeConfig.Instance.ObjectServer.RemoteBaseUrl = remoteBaseURL;
IdeaBladeConfig.Instance.ObjectServer.ServerPort = (int)double.Parse(serverPort);
IdeaBladeConfig.Instance.ObjectServer.ServiceName = serviceName;
IdeaBladeConfig.Instance.ObjectServer.ClientSettings.IsDistributed=true;

BeczkaModel= new BeczkaContainer();
BeczkaModel.AuthorizedThreadId = null;  
BeczkaModel.Connect();
```

Answer (score 2):

Data source key extensions and/or a custom IDataSourceKeyResolver are the way to handle different database connections.  It's important to realize that the EntityManager.Connect call is not connecting to a specific data source; it's actually connecting to a specific EntityService.  The way to connect to differing EntityService URLs is to use a ServiceKey.  More info here:  http://drc.ideablade.com/devforce-2012/bin/view/Documentation/connect-to-multiple-entityservers.

Answer (score 1):

You will be able to determine which database to connect to by implementing a custom DataSourceKeyResolver.

You will find additional information at http://drc.ideablade.com/devforce-2012/bin/view/Documentation/data-sources and a sample at http://drc.ideablade.com/devforce-2012/bin/view/Documentation/code-sample-custom-datasourcekeyresolver.

Answer (score 1):

To clarify sbellini's post, there are two ways to dynamically determine the database connection. The first and easier approach is to use Data Source Extensions. This is useful if you have a static list of database connections and want to select among the list at runtime. The second approach is to implement an IDataSourceKeyResolver. This allows you to determine the connection string entirely at runtime.

http://drc.ideablade.com/devforce-2012/bin/view/Documentation/data-sources

http://drc.ideablade.com/devforce-2012/bin/view/Documentation/code-sample-data-source-extensions

http://drc.ideablade.com/devforce-2012/bin/view/Documentation/code-sample-custom-datasourcekeyresolver